# How to search for a word which contains in a string

Tags: c#, wpf, string

I'm writing a software which can search for filenames.

Here is the string which I want to search (filename):

> C:\Boo\trunk\SQL\2015_ALTER_VIEW_BUCHUNGSLISTE_VIDEOKONFERENZ.sql

My query is:

> buchung

The query contains in the String but I don't know how to find it.

I tried the following functions:

```
if (filename.Contains("buchung"))
{
 SearchResultList.Add(fileName);
                    continue;
}


if (fileName.IndexOf("buchung", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
  {
                SearchResultList.Add(fileName);
                continue;
  }
```

What else can I use ?

Edit: Sorry, my query had a whitespace. That's the reason why I can't find anything.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you wanting to know if "buchung" is in the filename, or are you wanting to know where it is in the filename?

Comment: You are changing the variable name from buchung to query.  Pick one.  What is working and what is not?

Comment: sorry query is the stringname i'll change it

Answer (score 1):

Contains is case sensitive

Are you sure you are passing the correct stuff?
This works for me

```
string filename = @"C:\Boo\trunk\SQL\2015_ALTER_VIEW_BUCHUNGSLISTE_VIDEOKONFERENZ.sql";
string query = @"buchung";
Debug.WriteLine(filename.IndexOf(query, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: sorry. my query had a whitespace after the word "buchung "